# ERROR: No matching distribution found for snowflake-connector-python==2.5.0

Tags: python, pip, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to install the Snowflake Connector and am getting an error.

```
pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/v2.5.0/tested_requirements/requirements_36.reqs
pip install snowflake-connector-python==2.5.0
```

This results in:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement snowflake-connector-python==2.5.0 (from versions: 1.3.17, 1.3.18, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.6.12, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.9.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.2.6, 2.2.7, 2.2.8, 2.2.9, 2.2.10, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, 2.3.10, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.4.5, 2.4.6, 2.5.0, 2.5.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for snowflake-connector-python==2.5.0
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The Snowflake Connector for Python requires Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, or 3.9 to ensure that critical security fixes have been applied. In particular, PEP-476is required to ensure the Snowflake Connector for Python can verify certificates from the server.

More details:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-install.html
- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-install.html#python-package-installer-and-setup-tools

Comment: Yes, but thats not the problem. I am running Python 3.6.8